How can I find the endpoint for making GET and POST requests on a website?
I'm trying to figure out what endpoint and authentication a certain website requires so I can make GET and POST requests and obtain JSON files, similar to what I can do with the WordPress REST API.
Link example: https://portalodia.com/noticias/teresina/acusados-de-matar-dono-de-loterica-em-assalto-em-teresina-viram-reus-404889.html
